# Ambassador Edge Stack Host not generating ACME certificate

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, ambassador

I installed ambassador edge stack 1.4.2 community edition and added the host file as following.

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Host
metadata:
  name: ambassador-host
spec:
  hostname: quote.svc.ambassador.dev.platformer.com
  acmeProvider:
    email: nilesh93.j@gmail.com
```

This gets stuck in the following stage

```
NAME              HOSTNAME                                  STATE   PHASE COMPLETED      PHASE PENDING              AGE
ambassador-host   quote.svc.ambassador.dev.platformer.com   Error   ACMEUserRegistered   ACMECertificateChallenge   48s
```

This is my mappings file which I chose to run the example quote service.

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: quote
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  prefix: /quote
  service: http://quote.ambassador.svc
  host: quote.svc.ambassador.dev.platformer.com
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name:  acme-challenge-mapping
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  rewrite: ""
  prefix: /.well-known/acme-challenge
  service: http://quote.ambassador.svc
  host: quote.svc.ambassador.dev.platformer.com
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Cert manager?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with ambassador . I have installed cert-manager on kubernetes through this command.

```
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.15.1/cert-manager.yaml
```

check this https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/howtos/cert-manager/ for information .
You need to create ClusterIssuer and Certificate for Host.

Note:- "Cert-manager will automatically create and renew TLS certificates and store them in Kubernetes secrets for easy use in a cluster. Ambassador will automatically watch for secret changes and reload certificates upon renewal."

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: acme-challenge-mapping
spec:
  prefix: /.well-known/acme-challenge/
  rewrite: ""
  service: acme-challenge-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: acme-challenge-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8089
  selector:
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver: "true"
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Anishmourya/0a5c5087edb5f169ce4766319a873c82